# Grab output from ghostscript in python

Tags: python, ghostscript

I'm writing a script in python that uses gs but I cannot get the entire output from gs. Here's a minimal python code:

```
import subprocess

filename = "bw_dataset"
output = subprocess.Popen(["gswin64c.exe", "-o nul -sDEVICE=bbox", filename + ".pdf"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].decode()

print(output)
```

If I run the command in a terminal (windows) I'm getting some `%%BoundingBox` and `%%HiResBoundingBox` information that I need further on in my script:
[image]

However, `print(output)` from the above py script returns:
[image]

So the BoundingBox info is lost. How could I store that in a variable?

Comment: The command is executed successfully (from python).

Comment: what does just printing communicate output?

Comment: Stupid me... communicate()[1] contains the bounding box info.

Comment: yep, you can use `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`, I would still use check_output,`output = subprocess.check_output(["gswin64c.exe", "-o", "nul", "-sDEVICE=bbox", filename + ".pdf"],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`